# ActionResult parameters with no default constructor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

Obviously there are a number of ways to do this, but I thought I'd ask for a little feedback on benefits and drawbacks of the approaches.

First of all, the NerdDinner tutorial's Edit Action is in the form (say Form A):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection) {
```

It seems to me that if you shape your ViewModels well to match your views, that the approach Form B:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyViewModel mvm) {
```

just seems like a better, cleaner approach.  I then just map the VM properties to the Model properties and save.  However, if this ViewModel has other entities embedded in it that are initialized via the constructor (for example in the nerddinner tutorial), then this edit action fails if there is no default constructor and you'd have to use the first approach.

So, the first question is do you agree that generally Form B is usually better?  Are there drawbacks?

Secondly, it seems then if Form B is used, the decorator type validation would need to be in the ViewModel.  Are there advantages of embedding entities in ViewModels and keeping the validation at the entity level only?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty general SO question.

> the first question is do you agree that generally Form B is usually better?

The only time I do not use *Form B* is when I upload files.  Otherwise, I don't believe anyone should ever need to use *Form A*.  The reason I think people use *Form A* is a lack of understanding of the abilities of ASP.Net's version of MVC.

> Secondly, it seems then if Form B is used, the decorator type validation would need to be in the ViewModel.

Sort of / it Depends.  I'll give you an example:

```
public IValidateUserName
{
  [Required]
  string UserName { get; set; }
}

public UserModel
{
  string UserName { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(IValidateUserName))]
public UserValiationModel : UserModel
{
}
```

The validation decorator is in an interface.  I'm using the MetadataType on a derived class to validate the derived type.  I personally like this practice because it allows reusable validation and the MetadataType/Validation is NOT part of the ASP.NET core functionality, so it can be used outside of ASP.Net (MVC) application.

> Are there advantages of embedding entities in ViewModels ..

Yes, I do my absolute best to never pass a basic model to the view.  This is an example of what I don't do:

```
public class person { public Color FavoriteColor { get; set; } }

ActionResult Details()
{
  Person model = new Person();
  return this.View(model);
}
```

What happens when you want to pass more data to your view (for partials or layout data)?  That information is not Person relevant most of the time so adding it to the Person model makes no sense.  Instead, my models typically look like:

```
public class DetailsPersonViewModel()
{
  public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Details()
{
  DetailsPersonViewModel model = new DetailsPersonViewModel();
  model.Person = new Person();
  return this.View(model);
}
```

Now I can add required data the `DetailsPersonViewModel` that view needs beyond what a Person knows.  For example, lets say this is going to display a for with all the colors for the Person to pick a favorite.  All the possible colors aren't part of a person and shouldn't be part of the person Model, so I'd add them to the DetailPersonViewModel.

```
public class DetailsPersonViewModel()
{
  public Person Person { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<Color> Colors { get; set; }
}
```

> .. and keeping the validation at the entity level only?

`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` weren't designed to validate properties' properties, so doing something like:

```
public class DetailsPersonViewModel()
{
  [Required(property="FavoriteColor")]
  public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Doesn't exist and doesn't make sense.  Why ViewModel shouldn't contain the validation for the entity that needs validation.

> this edit action fails if there is no default constructor and you'd have to use the first approach.

Correct, but why would a ViewModel or a Entity in a ViewModel not have a parameterless constructor?  Sounds like a bad design and even if there is some requirement for this, it's easily solved by ModelBinding.  Here's an example:

```
// Lets say that this person class requires 
// a Guid for a constructor for some reason
public class Person
{
  public Person(Guid id){ }
  public FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class PersonEditViewModel
{
  public Person Person { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Edit()
{
  PersonEditViewModel model = new PersonEditViewModel();
  model.Person = new Person(guidFromSomeWhere);

  return this.View(PersonEditViewModel);
}

//View 
@Html.EditFor(m => m.Person.FirstName)

//Generated Html
<input type="Text" name="Person.FirstName" />
```

Now we have a form that a user can enter a new first name.  How do we get back the values in this constructor?  Simple, the ModelBinder does NOT care what model it is binding to, it just binds HTTP values to matching class properties.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(IPersonValidation))]
public class UpdatePerson
{
  public FirstName { get; set; }
}  

public class PersonUpdateViewModel
{
  public UpdatePerson Person { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(PersonUpdateViewModel model)
{
  // the model contains a .Person with a .FirstName of the input Text box
  // the ModelBinder is simply populating the parameter with the values
  // pass via Query, Forms, etc

  // Validate Model

  // AutoMap it or or whatever

  // return a view
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the thorough reply - excellent.  "I do my absolute best to never pass a basic model to the view" Sure, but that's not exactly what I was getting at.  The question was regarding whether ViewModels should have embedded entities like ViewModel.Person.Name vs just ViewModel.Name, that you unpack and map back to the deeper entity and whether you should use the decorator validation on ViewModel.Name not ViewModel.Person - Know what I mean??

Comment: I actually answered that question.  Yes it was long :)  I attempt to always use ViewModel.Person.Name, that being said it would require validation on Person not ViewModel as you can't really put validation on the ViewModel to validate a Person (you could but that not how the validation was intended to be used).

Comment: "the ModelBinder does NOT care what model it is binding to,"   Ok, so the validation decorators at the Person level will be handled in the same manner in the view if the elements are specified as ViewModel.Person.PropertyName right?  The same as if you passed in the Person model?

Comment: As long as the parameter signature matches.  That is to say that when you EditFor a class/property of MyClass1.Person.Name on the submit you can bind to <AnyClass>.Person.Name.  As in my example with `PersonEditViewModel` and `PersonUpdateViewModel`.  The classes don't have to match, just the hierarchy of property names.

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet taken a look at the NerDinner project, however, I generally try to avoid having a ViewModel in the POST of an action and instead, only have the elements of the "form" submitted.

For instance, if the ViewModel has a Dictionary that is used in some kind of dropdown, the entire dropdown will not be submitted, only the selected value.

My general approach is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id) 
{
     var form = _service.GetForm(id);

     var pageViewModel = BuildViewModel(form);

     return View(pageViewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, MyCustomForm form) 
{
     var isSuccess = _service.ProcessForm(id);    

      if(isSuccess){
         //redirect
      }

      //There was an error. Show the form again, but preserve the input values
      var pageViewModel = BuildViewModel(form);

      return View(pageViewModel);
}

private MyViewModel BuildViewModel(MyCustomForm form)
{
     var viewModel = new MyViewModel();

     viewModel.Form = form;
     viewModel.StateList = _service.GetStateList();

    return viewModel;
}
```

Comment: I guess I'm not quite clear by what you mean "the entire dropdown will not be submitted"?? I have a ViewModel with a selectlist.  Both the selected value as well the original values in the list make it back from the post...

Comment: How are ALL the values in a `<select>` posting to your Action?

Comment: They are not, only the selected value gets posted. This is why on both the GET and the POST I create the ViewModel. In the GET I start off with an empty form and in the POST, I have the submitted form. In each case I need to get the list of states.

Comment: @Erik The example in NerdDinner had a static string[] property in the ViewModel (with encapsulated data) that populates a SelectList Property in the constructor of the ViewModel. I presume that whenever MVC re-creates this object it cannot help but re-create the entire list as well.  The items are not posted, they're just re-created with the object...